# Removing ads from googletags in ajax application

Tags: ajax, google-dfp, google-tag-manager

I have an AJAX application which come down to 2 views: an overview and an article view. Both views have googletag ad slots.

I know how to load and display google tag ads into these defined slots, but is there a way to clear ads from certain slots?

I'm asking because when i go back from the article view to the overview, I want to clear the ads in the article view. (I know about the refresh option when loading a new article, but due to specific ads which are essentially overlays, this isn't an option).

Basically, I want the opposite of googletag.display('ad-id').

Comment: I dont think there is a way to do this in DFP... but why not just remove the element from the dom... or hide it?

Comment: That was impossible, as the ad was floating (and div elements are added to the body rather than the actual container). Fortunately I use sencha touch, so I could just remove the divs that don't carry the x-container class.